# Nice way to overcome the unquoted colon error in Ansible YAML files

Tags: yaml, ansible

It seems that Ansible fails to parse things like:

```
 with_items:
    - { regexp:'^AcceptEnv\s', line:'AcceptEnv LANG LC_* P4* GIT_* HGUSER RD_*' }

          ^
```

> This one looks easy to fix.  There seems to be an extra unquoted colon
>   in the line and this is confusing the parser. It was only expecting to
>   find one free colon. The solution is just add some quotes around the
>   colon, or quote the entire line after the first colon.

What would be a nice and clean way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a space after the colon. Like this:

```
  with_items:
    - { regexp: '^AcceptEnv\s', line: 'AcceptEnv LANG LC_* P4* GIT_* HGUSER RD_*' }
```

Debug will output:

```
ok: [default] => (item={'regexp': '^AcceptEnv\\s', 'line': 'AcceptEnv LANG LC_* P4* GIT_* HGUSER RD_*'}) => {
    "item": {
        "line": "AcceptEnv LANG LC_* P4* GIT_* HGUSER RD_*", 
        "regexp": "^AcceptEnv\\s"
    }, 
    "msg": "^AcceptEnv\\s=AcceptEnv LANG LC_* P4* GIT_* HGUSER RD_*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May sound silly but a simple space after the colon does fix the problem:

```
- { regexp: '^AcceptEnv\s', line: 'AcceptEnv LANG LC_* P4* GIT_* HGUSER RD_*' }
```